# UiTableView inside AlertView iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I wondering, how can I add uitableview in the Alert?

In my app I have an uitableview and if the user press in one row is going to show a dialog with a table (the table have some action).

How can I made this behavior in IOS 7?

I just try this library https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview but I couldn't fix my issue.

Regards,

David

Comment: Why couldn't you fix it? What specifically was wrong? Show some code for how you're using the library.

Comment: alertview's addSubView method wont work in iOS7...check the iOS7 design guideline..its mentioned there that you cannot customize alert views

Comment: thanks, I check the guideline but with this https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview code I can add sub view, I just want to add tableview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is not option to this in the standard `UIAlertView` you will have to make your own class.

Because the `UIAlertView` clear states:

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this
>   class is private and must not be modifie